# How to dynamically add/change list item using MVP pattern

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mvp

I've been trying to study MVP pattern and use it in my projects with *recyclerview*. (Just started to)
I'm little bit confused.

I have two cases:

1. I want to add a single (static) list item, if I get atleast 1 item from API call.

So, in Presenter I collect/fetch my list items from API call. I check if there's at least one instance, if so, I need to add a single "dummy" object. Where should this happen? In *MODEL* or *PRESENTER*?

2. I want to change outlook of my list items, when they are focused.

I've implemented my Adapter so it always calls Presenter (So I don't break MVP pattern). Is it okey to setFocusListener in ViewHolder and there change appearance of focused list item? Or does it contradicts MVP pattern?

Comment: ideal flow should be to access model from presenter, here you can add your object to the persistent storage. Your presenter should also be responsible to listen for any storage changes and update the UI accordingly.
Also, I don't like my adapter talking to the presenter directly, I do it via Fragment or Activity

Comment: @SarthakMittal But would it be okey to create two new objects in presenter and then set values to these objects? I also need to set ImageView  and Text - but I know I can't do that on presenter, as setting image would implement some android utils. What alternative do I have?

Comment: an easy way to think is: do UI related work in fragment/activity.

Comment: Well, all item info binding happens in ViewHolder. Shouldn't I assign data there?

Comment: r u following MVVM? you can assign data there if you are

Comment: I'm following MVP pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153134/discussion-between-sarthak-mittal-and-petewonder).